# Change field value before save using Editor Datatables

Tags: datatables

I am trying to change the values of a field salary before save on database.

I am using the code below on PHP events:

```
->on( 'preCreate', function ( $editor, $values ) {
    $editor->field( 'salary' )->setValue( $editor->field( 'salary' ) / 100 );
} )
->on( 'preEdit', function ( $editor, $id, $values ) {
    $editor->field( 'salary' )->setValue( $editor->field( 'salary' ) / 100 );
} )
```

I need to divide the value by 100.

But it's not work.

Any help?